# call C# function from angular application

Tags: c#, angular

I have C# class that connect to RF reader for creating Hotel Lock Cards
i need to run this C# functions from my Angular web Application
any Ideas to perform this ?

this is C# class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CSharpDemo
{
    class Class1
    {
        [DllImport("LockSDK.dll", EntryPoint = "TP_Configuration")]
        public static extern int TP_Configuration(Int16 LockType);

        private static void IDD102_1002_Click()
        {
            //Set SDK
            Int16 locktype = 0;
              locktype = 5;
            

            int st = TP_Configuration(locktype);

            
            //CheckErr(st);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            IDD102_1002_Click();
        }
    }
```

how can i run it from angular web application

Answer (score 1):

You could create simple WebApi and expose the method you're trying to use. Then, you could just hit the web api from your angular application to get the result.

Comment: could you please clarify how to create  WebApi and expose the method

Comment: WebApi is just another type of the application that allows other services to contact your application using http/grpc. You could build it in a REST fashion or make it GRPC service (I would suggest to start with the REST approach for starters). Exposing the method means that it is declared in your WebApi as a public method in a controller.

For detailed explanation with examples, please refer to the docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-5.0